# capistrano shared/bin folder is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I am using capistrano for deployment, and for some reason my shared/bin folder is empty, and, well it should contain -rails, rake, bundle, setup, spring. now obviously I did something wrong, but as I am new to capistrano, I have no Idea what it is, because it is in my git repository, and as far as I know it copies the entire thing from the repository. since I am not sure wether it is relavent or not, I will just put everything I changed reguarding the capistrano deployment.
here's my deploy.rb

```
lock '3.4.0'
# application settings
set :application, 'SomeApplication'
set :user, 'someuser'
#set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:someapp/someappserver.git'
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 5


#git settings
set :scm,           :git
set :branch,        "master"
set :repo_url,    "git@bitbucket.org:someapplication/someapplicationserver.git"
set :deploy_via,    :remote_cache


set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.1'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "#{fetch(:default_env)[:rvm_bin_path]}/rvm ruby-#{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec rake"


# dirs we want symlinked to the shared folder
# during deployment
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}


set :pg_database, "someapp_production"
set :pg_user, "someapp_production"
set :pg_ask_for_password, true


namespace :deploy do

  task :config_nginx do
    pre = File.basename(previous_release)
    cur = File.basename(release_path)
    run "#{sudo} sed 's/#{pre}/#{cur}/g' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default"
  end

  task :restart_thin_server do
    run "cd #{previous_release}; source $HOME/.bash_profile && thin stop -C thin_config.yml"
    run "cd #{release_path}; source $HOME/.bash_profile && thin start -C thin_config.yml"
  end

  task :restart_nginx do
    run "#{sudo} service nginx restart"
  end


  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      #
      # The capistrano-unicorn-nginx gem handles all this
      # for this example
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

here is my deploy/production.rb

```
# production deployment
set :stage, :production
# use the master branch of the repository
set :branch, "master"
# the user login on the remote server
# used to connect and deploy
set :deploy_user, "someuser"
# the 'full name' of the application
set :full_app_name, "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}"
# the server(s) to deploy to
server 'someserver.cloudapp.net', user: 'someuser', roles: %w{web app db}, primary: true
# the path to deploy to
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:deploy_user)}/apps/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"
# set to production for Rails
set :rails_env, :production
```

and here is my cap file

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
 require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
 require 'capistrano/bundler'
 require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
 require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

require 'capistrano/thin'
require 'capistrano/postgresql'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: Do you have all required files under `bin/` in your repo?

Comment: No, without the rails.rb it can't start - I could just copy it, but that would be a bad solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. And I found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243043/cannot-start-rails-4-console-on-production-server

Answer (score 6):

like @emj365 said
just remove bin form your linked_dirs in config/deploy.rb

> set :linked_dirs, %w{<s>bin</s> log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

Comment: Can you please explain why you removed the bin from linked_dirs. It worked for me but I want to understand why.

Comment: linked_dirs are not deployed. Is useful for log (you doesn't want to deploy your local logs), tmp/cache (you doesn't want to deploy your local cache), etc...

Answer (score 0):

@gilmishal Kindly check with this link .. [capistrano-deploy-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825872/capistrano-deploy-configuration/2883263)

And keep your eye on directory path where i did mistake many a times

```
# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'  # This conf is by default
```

Hope it will solve your problem