# Capistrano Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, capistrano

I've deployed a rails app using capistrano, puma, and nginx. I'm trying to enable rails console via this gem `capistrano-rails-console`, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
[d2184014] Command: bundle exec rails console production 
bash: bundle: command not found
```

I think the probably has to do with not using the right paths. This is what the path to db:migrate looks like:

`[45538ab7] Command: cd /home/USER/apps/APP/releases/20150711230709 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate )`

How can I have `cap production rails:console` from that gem call bundle using that path?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this because I had the same problem and this question was the first result that I get with google.

I solved this problem with the [capistrano rails console gem](https://github.com/ydkn/capistrano-rails-console) and after removed the bin directory from the deploy.rb file ([you should read this answer related with this last part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324669))